# What happened to my associated accounts list?

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, linked-accounts

["Accounts" tab on my profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/56285/jonik?tab=accounts) only lists Area 51, here and on all other SE sites ([example](https://askubuntu.com/users/928/jonik?tab=accounts)) that I'm using. Thing is, I have about 20-30 accounts linked to each other (see e.g. my [SE network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/8649d71c-a1a6-49ac-8128-0306b4a824ce)).

What's up with that?

NB: I didn't notice any bugs besides the account list being wrong (auto-login across SE works fine, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doh!

A bit of fallout from merging [Guitars](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6320/guitars) into [Music](https://music.stackexchange.com/), it has been rectified.
Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks! I just created account on music.SE too, which caused my sole [guitars answer](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1999/what-is-the-difference-between-solo-and-improvisation/2001#2001) to be correctly re-credited to me. Everything seems back to normal now.